# What's the equivalent of CastleWindsor's container.Release in LightInject?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, light-inject

I saw ASP.NET Web API dependency injection in Seemann's site. It uses CastleWindsor though.

```
request.RegisterForDispose(
            new Release(
                () => this.container.Release(controller)));
```

What's the equivalent of CastleWindsor's container.Release in LightInject?

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really a Release method in LightInject. Disposable services are registered either with the PerScopeLifetime og the PerRequestLifetime.

These services are disposed when the surrounding Scope is disposed.

```
container.Register<IFoo, DisposableFoo>(new PerScopeLifetime())

using(container.BeginScope())
{
    var foo = container.GetInstance<IFoo>()
} -- foo is disposed here
```

LightInject.WebApi provides an integration for Web Api that takes care of disposing controllers when the web request ends.